# Подскажите как достать нужный элемент вложенного forEach?

Tags: javascript

Есть основной `like-anchor` у которого внутри `like-svg` и `unlike-svg`
у второго `unlike-svg` есть также класс `show` который переписывает его `CSS` с `display:none` на `display:block`

Проблема в том что я не знаю как в **js** внутри цикла **forEach** изменить тот элемент на который кликнули ибо у стрелочных функции нету своего **this**

```js
const likes = [...document.querySelectorAll(".like-anchor")];
let likeSvg = document.querySelectorAll(".like-svg");
let unlikeSvg = document.querySelectorAll(".unlike-svg");

likes.forEach(like => {
  like.onclick = () => {
    
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background:gray;
}
.unlike-svg {
  display:none;
}
.like-svg {
  display:none;
}
.show {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<h1> -----1 -----</h1>

<div class="employer">
<span class="like-count"> 24 K </span>
 <a class="like-anchor" href="javascript:void(0);">   
  <svg class="unlike-svg show" width="35px" height="33px" viewBox="0 0 35 33" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
      <defs></defs>
      <g id="desktop" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
          <g id="Team" transform="translate(-683.000000, -1300.000000)" fill-rule="nonzero" stroke="#FFFFFF">
              <g id="Group-29-Copy-4" transform="translate(130.000000, 1030.000000)">
                  <g id="Group-2" transform="translate(427.000000, 0.000000)">
                      <g id="chef-coffee-cup-887827">
                          <g id="LIke" transform="translate(82.000000, 265.000000)">
                              <g id="actions---like" transform="translate(0.416667, 0.125000)">
                                  <g id="Group-7">
                                      <g id="Group-28" transform="translate(45.000000, 0.000000)">
                                          <path d="M23.5319265,6 C28.4564209,6 32.4583333,10.105125 32.4583333,15.1763125 C32.4583333,21.38525 27.3098876,28.2501875 17.193131,36.0094375 L16.2291667,36.75 L15.2652024,36.0094375 C5.1484457,28.2501875 0,21.38525 0,15.1763125 C0,10.1025625 3.99947815,6 8.9264068,6 C11.9424466,6 14.6128225,7.5400625 16.2291667,9.900125 C17.8455108,7.5400625 20.5158867,6 23.5319265,6 Z" id="Shape"></path>
                                      </g>
                                  </g>
                              </g>
                          </g>
                      </g>
                  </g>
              </g>
          </g>
      </g>
  </svg>

  <svg class="like-svg" width="33px" height="31px" viewBox="0 0 33 31" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

      <defs></defs>
      <g id="desktop" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
          <g id="Team" transform="translate(-1078.000000, -840.000000)">
              <g id="Group-29-Copy-3" transform="translate(126.000000, 568.000000)">
                  <g id="Group-5" transform="translate(854.000000, 0.000000)">
                      <g id="KgMvDCAz">
                          <g id="Group-4" transform="translate(95.000000, 267.000000)">
                              <g id="LIke">
                                  <polygon id="Shape" points="0 0 41 0 41 41 0 41"></polygon>
                                  <g id="actions---like" transform="translate(3.416667, 5.125000)" fill="#FFFFFF" fill-rule="nonzero">
                                      <path d="M23.5319265,1.7069679e-15 C28.4564209,1.7069679e-15 32.4583333,4.105125 32.4583333,9.1763125 C32.4583333,15.38525 27.3098876,22.2501875 17.193131,30.0094375 L16.2291667,30.75 L15.2652024,30.0094375 C5.1484457,22.2501875 0,15.38525 0,9.1763125 C0,4.1025625 3.99947815,5.689893e-16 8.9264068,5.689893e-16 C11.9424466,5.689893e-16 14.6128225,1.5400625 16.2291667,3.900125 C17.8455108,1.5400625 20.5158867,0 23.5319265,1.7069679e-15 Z" id="Shape"></path>
                                  </g>
                              </g>
                          </g>
                      </g>
                  </g>
              </g>
          </g>
      </g>
  </svg>
</a>

<!--- 2 -->
 <h1> -----2 -----</h1>
<div class="employer">
<span class="like-count"> 24 K </span>
 <a class="like-anchor" href="javascript:void(0);">   
  <svg class="unlike-svg show" width="35px" height="33px" viewBox="0 0 35 33" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
      <defs></defs>
      <g id="desktop" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
          <g id="Team" transform="translate(-683.000000, -1300.000000)" fill-rule="nonzero" stroke="#FFFFFF">
              <g id="Group-29-Copy-4" transform="translate(130.000000, 1030.000000)">
                  <g id="Group-2" transform="translate(427.000000, 0.000000)">
                      <g id="chef-coffee-cup-887827">
                          <g id="LIke" transform="translate(82.000000, 265.000000)">
                              <g id="actions---like" transform="translate(0.416667, 0.125000)">
                                  <g id="Group-7">
                                      <g id="Group-28" transform="translate(45.000000, 0.000000)">
                                          <path d="M23.5319265,6 C28.4564209,6 32.4583333,10.105125 32.4583333,15.1763125 C32.4583333,21.38525 27.3098876,28.2501875 17.193131,36.0094375 L16.2291667,36.75 L15.2652024,36.0094375 C5.1484457,28.2501875 0,21.38525 0,15.1763125 C0,10.1025625 3.99947815,6 8.9264068,6 C11.9424466,6 14.6128225,7.5400625 16.2291667,9.900125 C17.8455108,7.5400625 20.5158867,6 23.5319265,6 Z" id="Shape"></path>
                                      </g>
                                  </g>
                              </g>
                          </g>
                      </g>
                  </g>
              </g>
          </g>
      </g>
  </svg>

  <svg class="like-svg" width="33px" height="31px" viewBox="0 0 33 31" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

      <defs></defs>
      <g id="desktop" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
          <g id="Team" transform="translate(-1078.000000, -840.000000)">
              <g id="Group-29-Copy-3" transform="translate(126.000000, 568.000000)">
                  <g id="Group-5" transform="translate(854.000000, 0.000000)">
                      <g id="KgMvDCAz">
                          <g id="Group-4" transform="translate(95.000000, 267.000000)">
                              <g id="LIke">
                                  <polygon id="Shape" points="0 0 41 0 41 41 0 41"></polygon>
                                  <g id="actions---like" transform="translate(3.416667, 5.125000)" fill="#FFFFFF" fill-rule="nonzero">
                                      <path d="M23.5319265,1.7069679e-15 C28.4564209,1.7069679e-15 32.4583333,4.105125 32.4583333,9.1763125 C32.4583333,15.38525 27.3098876,22.2501875 17.193131,30.0094375 L16.2291667,30.75 L15.2652024,30.0094375 C5.1484457,22.2501875 0,15.38525 0,9.1763125 C0,4.1025625 3.99947815,5.689893e-16 8.9264068,5.689893e-16 C11.9424466,5.689893e-16 14.6128225,1.5400625 16.2291667,3.900125 C17.8455108,1.5400625 20.5158867,0 23.5319265,1.7069679e-15 Z" id="Shape"></path>
                                  </g>
                              </g>
                          </g>
                      </g>
                  </g>
              </g>
          </g>
      </g>
  </svg>
</a>
</div>

 <!-- 3 -->
 <h1> -----3 -----</h1>
 <div class="employer">
<span class="like-count"> 24 K </span>
 <a class="like-anchor" href="javascript:void(0);">   
  <svg class="unlike-svg show" width="35px" height="33px" viewBox="0 0 35 33" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
      <defs></defs>
      <g id="desktop" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
          <g id="Team" transform="translate(-683.000000, -1300.000000)" fill-rule="nonzero" stroke="#FFFFFF">
              <g id="Group-29-Copy-4" transform="translate(130.000000, 1030.000000)">
                  <g id="Group-2" transform="translate(427.000000, 0.000000)">
                      <g id="chef-coffee-cup-887827">
                          <g id="LIke" transform="translate(82.000000, 265.000000)">
                              <g id="actions---like" transform="translate(0.416667, 0.125000)">
                                  <g id="Group-7">
                                      <g id="Group-28" transform="translate(45.000000, 0.000000)">
                                          <path d="M23.5319265,6 C28.4564209,6 32.4583333,10.105125 32.4583333,15.1763125 C32.4583333,21.38525 27.3098876,28.2501875 17.193131,36.0094375 L16.2291667,36.75 L15.2652024,36.0094375 C5.1484457,28.2501875 0,21.38525 0,15.1763125 C0,10.1025625 3.99947815,6 8.9264068,6 C11.9424466,6 14.6128225,7.5400625 16.2291667,9.900125 C17.8455108,7.5400625 20.5158867,6 23.5319265,6 Z" id="Shape"></path>
                                      </g>
                                  </g>
                              </g>
                          </g>
                      </g>
                  </g>
              </g>
          </g>
      </g>
  </svg>

  <svg class="like-svg" width="33px" height="31px" viewBox="0 0 33 31" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

      <defs></defs>
      <g id="desktop" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
          <g id="Team" transform="translate(-1078.000000, -840.000000)">
              <g id="Group-29-Copy-3" transform="translate(126.000000, 568.000000)">
                  <g id="Group-5" transform="translate(854.000000, 0.000000)">
                      <g id="KgMvDCAz">
                          <g id="Group-4" transform="translate(95.000000, 267.000000)">
                              <g id="LIke">
                                  <polygon id="Shape" points="0 0 41 0 41 41 0 41"></polygon>
                                  <g id="actions---like" transform="translate(3.416667, 5.125000)" fill="#FFFFFF" fill-rule="nonzero">
                                      <path d="M23.5319265,1.7069679e-15 C28.4564209,1.7069679e-15 32.4583333,4.105125 32.4583333,9.1763125 C32.4583333,15.38525 27.3098876,22.2501875 17.193131,30.0094375 L16.2291667,30.75 L15.2652024,30.0094375 C5.1484457,22.2501875 0,15.38525 0,9.1763125 C0,4.1025625 3.99947815,5.689893e-16 8.9264068,5.689893e-16 C11.9424466,5.689893e-16 14.6128225,1.5400625 16.2291667,3.900125 C17.8455108,1.5400625 20.5158867,0 23.5319265,1.7069679e-15 Z" id="Shape"></path>
                                  </g>
                              </g>
                          </g>
                      </g>
                  </g>
              </g>
          </g>
      </g>
  </svg>
</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: А вы не используйте стрелочную функцию!

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko без него никак

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете получить элемент по которому произошел клик из объекта event, который передается в обработчик.
Для этого вам нужно его принять, и уже из него получить event.currentTarget.

```js
const likes = [...document.querySelectorAll(".like-anchor")];
let likeSvg = document.querySelectorAll(".like-svg");
let unlikeSvg = document.querySelectorAll(".unlike-svg");

likes.forEach(like => {
  like.onclick = (e) => {
    const element = e.currentTarget;
    const svgElements = element.querySelectorAll("svg");
  }
})
```

Comment: эммм ну а как менять классы ??

Comment: У вас в переменной `element` будет ссылка на элемент, по которому произошел клик. Поэтому чтобы добавить класс к этому элементу можно написать что-то вроде `element.className += " show";`

Comment: нет проблема в том что при console.log(element) у меня выводит тег like-anchor а у него  я не могу менять классы мне надо достать элементы которые внутри него (два svg у одного класс show) а уже у них менять классы.Одного скрыть другого показать .Вот в чем проблема

Comment: Из вашего вопроса это не следует))). Но ничего не мешает найти вложенные элементы `element.querySelectorAll("svg")`. И работать с ними.

Comment: я не буду принимать ваш ответ он не решил мою проблему

Comment: так я не прошу его принимать, я пытаюсь помочь решить проблему)

Comment: спасибо большое ваш ответ решил мою проблему .Плюс от меня :)

Comment: Отлично! Я рад что смог помочь.

Answer (score 1):

Параметр `like` захвачен стрелочной функцией-обработчиком:

```
likes.forEach(like => {
  like.onclick = () => {
    like.querySelector(".like-svg").classList.toggle("show");
    like.querySelector(".unlike-svg").classList.toggle("show");
  }
})
```

Comment: да но мы к like-у ничего не добавляем так бы и я сам  сделал.Внутри него есть два svg с классом show и без их я меняю.Но все равно спасибо за ответ.

Comment: @Demon__ANT Вы видите код в ответе?

Comment: нет ...у вас тоже не было ...